# Parsing string with nested information

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation, data-structures, parsing

I am trying to parse a string, but I have no idea how to solve the following problem

```
problem = "a { b { c d } e } aa { bb cc }";
answer = {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", "e"}, {"aa", "bb"}, {"aa", "cc"}};
```

So the answer is a path in each sub-list of the list

Any suggestions ?

Comment: can you please  enter the problem is Mathematica synatx? Is the problem meant to be: `problem = a { b { c d } e } a a { b b c c }` ?  I do not understand what `path node list of the tree information` here. You mean `TreeForm` ? can you give a link that explains what it is?

Comment: now modified. sorry for ambiguity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the requirement but this seems to work for the example at least:

```
problem = "a { b { c d } e } aa { bb cc }";

Map[Flatten, StringSplit[problem] //. 
 {head___, x_, "{", Shortest[y__], "}", tail___} :> 
 {head, Sequence @@ Thread[{x, {y}}], tail}]

(* {{"a", "b", "c"}, {"a", "b", "d"}, {"a", "e"}, {"aa", "bb"}, {"aa", "cc"}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks Woods. I think you gave me a correct answer!

Comment: some explanation would have been helpful.