# Converting path list to the nested list

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, conversion

I'm trying to convert the plain path list to the nested tree list like the following codes.

```
problem = {{"a", "b", "b1", "c1"}, {"a", "b", "b1", "c2"}, {"a", "b", "b1", "c3"}, 
           {"a", "b", "b2"}, {"aa", "b", "b1" }};

answer = {{"a", {"b", {"b1", {"c1", "c2", "c3"}, "b2"}}}, {"aa", {"b", {"b1"}}}}
```

For reference, I posted the question which is the above answer. ([Parsing string with nested information](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/71918/parsing-string-with-nested-information))

My wrong solution using `GroupBy` and `RightFold` is

```
rightFold[fun_, {}, rhs_] := rhs;
rightFold[fun_, {head___, prev_}, rhs_] := rightFold[fun, {head}, fun[prev, rhs]];

re1 = GroupBy[problem, Most -> Last];

kvs = Thread[{Keys[re1], Values[re1]}];
wrong = rightFold[List, #[[1]], #[[2]]] & /@ kvs
```

`wrong` is

> ```
> {{"a", {"b", {"b1", {"c1", "c2", "c3"}}}}, {"a", {"b", {"b2"}}}, {"aa", {"b", b1"}}}
> ```

in which `"{"a", {"b", {"b2"}}"` is not right.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your `answer` is a little bit inconsistent. Should not it be: `{ "a", {"b", {"b1", {"c1", "c2", "c3"}, "b2"}}, "aa", {"b", {"b1"}} }`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This is slightly different from your `answer` but it is consistent:

```
ClearAll[h];
h[{{}}] := Sequence[];    
h[list : {{__} ..}] := Normal @ GroupBy[list, First -> Rest, h];

Block[{Rule},
 Rule[x_] := x;
 Rule[x_, y_List] := Sequence[x, y];

 h[problem]
 ]
```

> ```
> {"a", {"b", {"b1", {"c1", "c2", "c3"}, "b2"}}, "aa", {"b", {"b1"}}}
> ```

---

#### This gives exactly the result you need:

```
ClearAll[h];
h[{{}}] = {};
h[list : {{__} ..}] := Normal @ GroupBy[list, First -> Rest, h];
```

So the trick is to recursively use `h` with 3rd argument of `GroupBy`.

```
h[problem]

% /. Rule -> (List[#, Join @@ #2] &) /. {} -> Sequence[]
```

> ```
> {"a"->{"b"->{"b1"->{"c1"->{}, "c2"->{}, "c3"->{}}, "b2"->{}}}, "aa"->{"b"->{"b1"->{}}}}
>
> {{"a", {"b", {"b1", {"c1", "c2", "c3"}, "b2"}}}, {"aa", {"b", {"b1"}}}}
> ```

One could probably use some other function instead of `Rest` to avoid those replacements at the end. But in that case one will waste time on defining proper `DownValues` for such function. (*it may be usefull to do so maybe*)

Comment: I am learning so much from your solution, thank you!

Comment: @marsiano I'm learning so much from your question!

Comment: huh, recursive use of `GroupBy`. Nice, +1.